# Regex for first name and last name in form

Tags: php, regex

I needed a regex to validate wether first and last name were provided corectly or not. Well This is what i came up with:

`preg_match('/^[\p{L}]{4,25}[\s][\p{L}]{4,25}$/u', Form::post('name'))`

This one works if string contains:

- `word (4-25 chars long and utf8 chars allowed)`
- `space`
- `word (4-25 chars long and utf8 chars allowed)`

which rather is fine, but it seems too much complex for my script
is there a way to convert that regex so it will meet same conditions but has kind of "global" characters range instead, something like this:

- `(word space word){8,50}`

also optionaly it could have second space and third word in case that some foreign person would want to use my site

any help will be appriciated:)

Comment: Joe O'Donnell called. He wants to know why you locked him out of your website.

Comment: Why do you want to validate names? I think my actual lastname (3 words with spaces in between) would not pass either.

Comment: how than you would protect your website against malicious users which would want to exploit name field. if you at least escape that field `Joe O'Donnell` name will be screwed up already, unless you wont but than you have to deal with possibility of using `'` while executing query's

Comment: @PatrickMevia That's another question altogether, but if you don't know how to escape text before inserting it into database queries, then I think you should stop whatever you're doing and find a competent programmer to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that name validation is a bad idea in and of itself (see [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)), and that your regex can be simplified syntactically to

```
/^\pL{4,25}\s\pL{4,25}$/u
```

yes, it is possible, but ugly. You would need to use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that there is only one space, and that it's neither at the end nor at the start of the string:

```
/^(?=\S+\s\S+$)[\pL\s]{8,50}$/u
```

If you want to allow more spaces/words, you can use

```
/^(?=\S+(?:\s\S+)+$)[\pL\s]{8,50}$/u
```

Comment: Thank you, well explained and delivered:)